# Puppet configuration for multiple classes in a module

Tags: puppet

I'd like to use and configure the [puppet-nginx](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/) module, although this is a general question about Puppet configuration.

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

class nginx-setup {
    class { 'nginx': }
}

include nginx-setup
```

**Works great!** Now, if I follow the docs for configuration I end up with something like this:

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

class nginx-setup {
    class { 'nginx': }

    class { 'nginx::package':
        package_source => 'nginx-mainline'
    }
}

include nginx-setup
```

**Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Nginx::Package] is already declared**

I tried `include nginx` instead of my first class declaration, but I think the module's `init.pp` is declaring the `nginx::package` class already and I still get duplicate declaration error. Even if that worked, what if I wanted to apply more configurations to another class within the nginx module? For example:

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

class nginx-setup {
    class { 'nginx': }

    class { 'nginx::package':
        package_source => 'nginx-mainline'
    }

    class { 'nginx::config': 
        nginx_error_log => 'syslog:server=localhost',
    }
}

include nginx-setup
```

**Many duplicate definitions!**

So it feels like I should be passing everything required into my initial class declaration, but I can't seem to find the right way to do it. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Consider using Hiera after all, for this module is tricky to use otherwise, due to some shortcomings in Puppet's handling of class parameters.

---

Long answer:

That's a loaded question, actually, even though it should not be. You correcly inferred the gist already. But let's take it step-by-step.

## Module structure

It is now considered best practice (citation needed, although Ryan Coleman from Puppet Labs mentioned this in a recent presentation at FOSDEM) to expose all tunables of a module in its central class (here, class `nginx`).

This way, it is clear for the user that they need to look up the appropriate parameter for this one class, instead of going on a hunt for the appropriate class to tune.

The `nginx` module you picked seems to adopt this in large parts, but not consequently.

## Hacks using defined()

As you have noticed, the module author added some shortcuts to allow you to declare your classes "safely" **if** you make sure the `nginx::config` class is encountered before the `nginx` class proper, lexically.

This is dangerous, because in a complex manifest, this might not be easy to assert.

## include vs. class { }

Class parameters are problematic, because they lead to `include` being less safe than it used to be, because they don't mix well with `class { 'name': ... }` style declarations. The latter are always bad news because they have to be unique, as you are now experiencing.

It is best to stick to `include` as much as possible, which leads to the next issue.

## Hiera

With parameterized classes, you really want to adopt Hiera as soon as possible. Defining class parameters as data is almost universally superior to doing it in the manifest. I understand the desire to stick to simple constructs first, but due to the issue described above, it can really make life harder on yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it was module-specific. `jfryman/puppet-nginx` module classes are loaded automatically [except for nginx::config](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/init.pp#L222) (unless it isn't declared already) and most other classes inherit their settings from nginx::config. The correct solution for this module is;

```
class nginx-setup {
    class { '::nginx::config':
        http_access_log => 'syslog:server=localhost,tag=nginx,severity=info',
        nginx_error_log => 'syslog:server=localhost,tag=nginx,severity=info',
    }

    class { '::nginx':
        package_source => 'nginx-mainline',
    }
}
include nginx-setup
```

`jfryman/puppet-nginx` is moving towards [Hiera configurations](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx#hiera-support) and this might not work for long. I wanted a pure Puppet solution (to learn) before integrating Hiera but I wouldn't recommend it for everyone...